# VersionConflict I don't know how to fix

Tags: python, version

My problem is I can not build `c2cgeoportal` app due to a weird error I can not fix.

Since the beginning, I've been following the tutorial posted on the [project website](https://camptocamp.github.io/c2cgeoportal/master/index.html), but now I have an blocking error.

I've been trying to deploy the application (it's described [here](https://geomapfish-demo.camptocamp.net/docmaster/integrator/docker.html)). When I run this command:

```
make -f <xxx.mk> build
```

(I replaced the filename with correct value) I get the same error every time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".build/venv/bin/pot-create", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "<path>/.build/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lingua/extract.py", line 301, in main
    register_extractors()
  File "<path>/.build/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lingua/extractors/__init__.py", line 152, in register_extractors
    extractor = entry_point.load(require=True)
  File "<path>/.build/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2290, in load
    self.require(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<path>/.build/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2307, in require
    items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer)
  File "<path>/.build/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 858, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (dogpile.cache 0.6.2 (<path>/.build/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('dogpile.cache<0.6'))
CONST_Makefile:703: recipe for target 'sample_app/locale/sample_app-client.pot' failed
make: *** [sample_app/locale/sample_app-client.pot] Error 1
```

The thing is I found the file with PIP requirements and changed the version of the `dogpile.cache` library to lower than `0.6.0` (precisely `0.5.7`) and it didn't work. There is no piece of code in the whole project that would require this library in any other version. I don't know if there is any cache mechanism or something else, but I spent almost the whole day trying to fix this, no success.

The project uses virtualenv (it was generated by previous steps), it's running with Python 2.7, I am using Linux Mint 18 (if anything of it matters).

Without fixing this, I am not able to run docker container with the application, so I am grounded. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you show me the output of running `pip list` in your virual environment? It seems you already have a version greater than `0.6 ` installed

Comment: I had version `0.6.2`, but I removed it and installed `0.5.7`. Currently, I don't have access to the computer it's set up, but I can assure you I double-checked that this library in version `0.6.x` is no longer installed. That's why I ask for your help :)

Comment: If `pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (dogpile.cache 0.6.2 (<path>/.build/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('dogpile.cache<0.6'))` this line keeps popping out in your logs then you should double check because it's telling you that `dogpile.cache 0.6.2` is actually installed. Maybe on a virtualenv or something?

Comment: @yorodm I know what this line suggests, but this lib in version `0.6.2` is not installed anymore. It was, I removed it and I installed the previous version of it (`0.5.7`). It didn't fix the problem, though.